# Creating alias for the db tableD Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to design some Django models my question is.

How do you create an alias for the db table when if differs from what I want it to be call in the model?

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

database table

```
core_Person
```

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#table-names
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#db-table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class Person(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

  class Meta:
    db_table = 'core_Person'
```

from the [documenation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#db-table):

> To override the database table name, use the db_table parameter in
>   class Meta.

If you're not familiary with Meta options, django gives you some information about them [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#meta-options)

Answer (score 1):

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'core_Person'
```